# In Python, how to reduce the precision of a float to a given step size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, precision

I have a float that can have arbitrary precision, and a minimum step size that indicates the minimum amount of this number can be increased / decreased by:

```
num = 3.56891211101
min_step = 0.005
```

I'd like to have a function that takes this `num` and the `step_size` and rounds the `num` to that given `min_step`. So in this case the result would be `3.570`.

I attempted this:

```
num = 3.56891211101
min_step = 0.005

def myround(x, base):
    return base * round(x / base)

x = myround(num, min_step)
print(x)
>>> 3.5700000000000003
```

...it's close, but not quite. I would like the output to be the same as if:

```
y = 3.570
print(y)
>>> 3.57
```

What's a simple way of accomplishing this?

I'm on Python 3.8

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Thanks @PranavHosangadi, I'm well aware. Being practical, clearly the output of those two prints is different. How to fix that rounding function so that it gives the output I get on the second print?

Comment: Pranav's point is that you're never going to reliably get the same output based on the limitations of floating point arithmetic. Though you may be aware of the topic, you may want to read up on it a little more if you don't grok that point yet.

Comment: I understand the limitation of the calculation I've done and why that ...00003 shows up there. Is there a way to get that first print to print 3.57?

Comment: No, there's no reliable way to make sure that an arbitrary x and base results in the exact value you want it to.

Comment: @Randy I solved it below. Obviously the result is "less precise", but gets the output I needed. Check it out. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I get it, thanks @MarkDickinson. In my case I was not concerned with precision. I was concerned with getting rid of the ...0003 in that first number because I have an API that will refuse such precision. So its OK for me to get a less precise number, as long as it abides by the given step_size. See how I solved it below. If you can think of a simpler way, please let me know - that whole conversion to string feels hacky but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Python implementations (including the CPython reference implementation) use IEE 754 floating point numbers. As a result, they are not accurate for decimal values.

The canonic way is to use the decimal module:

```
from decimal import Decimal, Context

num = 3.56891211101
c = Context(prec=3)
x= c.create_decimal(num)
print(x)
```

gives as expected

```
3.57
```

Comment: YES! Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Much better than my string conversion hack.

Comment: @EdyBourne: Didn't you want to round to a multiple of `0.005`? This answer simply rounds the float `num` to three *significant figures* (so will give a different number of places after the point, depending on the magnitude of the input) and turns it into a `Decimal` instance at the same time, which doesn't seem like what you were looking for. (E.g., what result would you want if `num = 3.56627`? What about `num = 12.56891211101` or `num = 0.8126666`?)

Comment: Re “Python uses IEE 754 floating point numbers”: The Python documentation does not specify this. Some Python implementations do, but one cannot rely on it simply based on the fact one is using Python.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right. I too often think CPython when speaking of Python, but other implementation exist, even if I have never heard of one using a floating point system other than IEE754.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
def myround(x, base):
    decimal_places = str(base)[::-1].find('.')
    precise = base * round(x / base)
    return round(precise, decimal_places)

x = myround(num, min_step)
print(x)
>>> 3.57

y = 3.570
print(y)
>>> 3.57
```

Hope its helpful to others.

Comment: Use the accepted answer instead. I'll leave this here for completeness sake, but the accepted answer is the way to go.